# How to perform pre-processing in batching for train input function in Tensorflow Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I have written a simple TF model using Estimator. The simple version worked but with large input size during training my code runs into Memory Error. For this I want to send data to my train function in batches and perform the pre-processing within batches instead of entire data. I have code below which runs into errors. Can someone kindly review and help me figure what is wrong -

```py
def train_fn_custom(features, labels, batch_size):
    print(type(features)) // gives <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    print(type(labels))
    def _preprocess_function(features, labels):        
        print(type(features)) // gives <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
        print(type(labels))
        features=tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(features, maxlen)
        features=sequence.pad_sequences(features, maxlen=maxlen)
        features=features.astype(np.float32)

        labels=utils.to_categorical(labels, nb_classes)
        labels=labels.astype(np.float32)
        return features, labels

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
    dataset = dataset.map(_preprocess_function)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

batch_size = 128
customTrain = lambda: train_fn_custom(X1, y_train, batch_size)
estimator_model.train(input_fn=customTrain, steps=10000)
```

Error:

```
in texts_to_sequences_generator
    for text in texts:
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 459, in __iter__
    "Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is "
TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
```

Comment: What are dataset_x, dataset_y type and shape? What is the error message?

Comment: Hi Sharky - I cleaned the post with code for understanding and added error msg as well.

Comment: dataset object passes tensors to `_preprocess_function`, hence the error. Also, at first you had some memory error, now you'er having another kind of error. Could you please make your question clearer

Comment: Thanks Sharky. Sorry for the unclear question earlier - I encounter the error above for "Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled". From documentation of tensorflow dataset API I understood that first step to wrap your data into Dataset is to use dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels)) and then do  dataset = dataset.map(_preprocess_function). When I check type of input to preprocess  it is <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>

Comment: You don't need iterator with estimator, just pass dataset, estimator will handle iteration

Comment: Thanks Sharky, I understand why we dont need iterator with estimator and removed that. However, the error still persists because in the preprocess function I am still iterating on tensor objects to perform the pre-processing in function - texts_to_sequences. This function like the name says does tokenization of my texts to sequences. Since the data is huge I was putting it in Dataset pre-processing function.

Comment: as i said, texts_to_sequences expects array, not tensor

Comment: I figured where the issue - I need to use from_generator instead of from_tensor_slices.

Comment: Looks like this solution also does not work because my texts_to_sequences is eventually still getting tensors in input. Any way to reuse the function without making changes?

Comment: You either need to wrap current function with `py_func` or try using `tfds.features.text.Tokenizer`. I'm not very familiar with this, so can't advise on how to use it in detail

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Sharky. I still don't have a solution but appreciate your help.